# Create an array of single-float from double-float in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

When I try to create a single-float array like this, i get:

```
(make-array 2 :element-type 'single-float :initial-contents #(3.0 4.0))
```

, i get the following error:

```
The value 3.0 is not of type SINGLE-FLOAT
```

Is there a way to create a single-float array from a simple vector of double-float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to create a single-float array like this, i get:
>
> ```
> (make-array 2 :element-type 'double-float :initial-contents #(3.0 4.0))
> ```

Are you trying to create an array of **single-floats** (what your text says) or an array of **double-floats** (what the code suggests)?  To create an array of **double-floats**, you'd use **(make-array … :element-type 'double-float …)**, and to create an array of **single-floats**, you'd use **(make-array … :element-type 'single-float …)**.  However, in either case, the elements in the *initial-elements* argument needs to match the specified type;  the HyperSpec entry for [**make-array**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ar.htm) says that:

> initial-contents is composed of a nested structure of sequences. The
>   numbers of levels in the structure must equal the rank of array. **Each
>   leaf of the nested structure must be of the type given by
>   element-type**.

Since a single-float and a double-float aren't the same type, you'll need to convert the data beforehand.  You could use **map** to create a result, or **map-into** if you want to create it first and then copy the results in. E.g.:

```
CL-USER> (map '(vector double-float *)
         #'(lambda (x) (float x 1.0d0))
         #(3.0 4.0))
#(3.0d0 4.0d0)
```

```
CL-USER> (map-into (make-array 2 :element-type 'double-float)
                   #'(lambda (x) (float x 1.0d0))
                   #(3.0 4.0))
#(3.0d0 4.0d0)
```

Those examples assume that you're trying to create an array of **double-floats**, which is what your *code* suggests.  If you just want an array of **single-floats**, then you can just the correct type:

```
CL-USER> (make-array 2 :element-type 'single-float :initial-contents #(3.0 4.0))
#(3.0 4.0)
```

Or, as [Svante noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767842/1281433), you can just write **#(3.0 4.0)** or **#(3.0s0 4.0s0)** directly.

Comment: Many thanks. I adapt your answer for single-float, and it works.

Comment: @Xaving what do you mean adapt it?  In the question you'd asked for a way to create a vector of double-floats from a vector of single-floats.  That's what this code does...

Comment: i asked the other way around. So in your Solution everything that is related to double, i replaced it with single-float.

Comment: @Xaving I'm glad the answer helps.  I see that your text asks to "to create a single-float array", but your code suggests that you were trying to create an array of type double-float, since you use `:element-type double-float`.

Comment: @Xaving But now the problem just disappears, right?  Since `(make-array 2 :element-type 'single-float :initial-contents #(3.0 4.0))` successfully returns `#(3.0 4.0)` (at least if ***read-default-float-format\*** is single-float).

Comment: Actually, in my sbcl Environment, #(3.0 4.0) is considered as double-float. Thank you for pointing to the use of the *read-default-float-format*.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a vector of single floats directly:

```
#(3.0s0 4.0s0)
```

For double floats use:

```
#(3.0d0 4.0d0)
```

The default read float type is given by `*read-default-float-format*`.  See [CLHS Chapter 2.3.2.2 (Syntax of a Float)](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_cbb.htm).

*Edit:* That means that the following does what you seem to want:

```
(make-array 2 :element-type 'single-float :initial-contents #(3.0s0 4.0s0))
```

If you have a *lot* of such expressions in your code, binding `*read-default-float-format*` globally before loading the affected source files might be worthwhile.

Comment: That provides a vector of single-floats, but the type won't be specialized for single-floats.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: yes, but that is irrelevant for `:initial-contents`.  I should perhaps be clearer about that.

Comment: does the LET make sense? Can it influence the reading of floats in a form it encloses?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Oh yeah, you'd have to ensure this at read time, so it doesn't like this.  Sorry!